# What is the purpose of decreased FLOPs and parameter size if they are not for increased speed?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, flops, densenet

CNN algorithms like DenseNet [DenseNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993) stress parameter efficiency, which usually results in less FLOPs. However, what I am struggling to understand is why this is important. For DenseNet, in particular, it has low inference speed. Isn't the purpose of decreased parameter size/FLOPs to decrease the time for inference? Is there another real world reason, such as perhaps less energy used, for these optimizations?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between overall inference time vs. per parameter/FLOPs training efficiency. Having lower parameter/FLOPs in training does not guarantee higher speed in inference. Because overall inference depends on the architecture and how predictions are computed.

Comment: If so, what is the purpose of being more parameter/flops efficient?

Comment: It is a measure to compare training efficiency.